# Android - Images.Media.insertImage is turning every pixel with alpha of 0 to black

Tags: android, bitmap

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), temp, "title", null);
        saveToast.show();
    }
```

Im trying to save the bitmap "temp" to the photo library. It saves fine, however every pixel that originally has an alpha of 0, is just turned black on the saved image. Where am I going wrong?

Is there a better way to save bitmaps to the photo library?

Bitmap being created:

```
temp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), lastImage);
Bitmap mutableBitmap = temp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Note lastImage is a png with some alpha of 0;

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this relates to your problem but here's a description of what happened:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/2614256

According to the discussion it is mainly because of alpha channel CYMK.

How is the bitmap created? If it is created manually I believe you need to make it ARGB.

Comment: I dont think that is it. I posted the code creating the bitmap above. It is ARGB_8888

Comment: @aaronmays0724 instead of explicitly passing `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`, would you try using `temp.getConfig()` instead?